# How to Decrease Request Size to insert data to multiple table? (Back4App)

Tags: back4app

I was inserting the data (Back4app) to two tables in the same time. But it took a lot of requests. I've tried it for 3 hours, and I've inserted 3.28k data. (There's no other action in that program) In the end, it took 6.88k requests. Is it ok about it? And how to decrease the request size?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), take the [SO tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You can create a cloud code function in order to do that. You call the cloud code function a single time (and it counts as only 1 api call) and you can do as many inserts as you want.